# Combine non unique worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 37 tabs. each tab has between 37 and 60 columns each with headers and then values going down the rows. The number of rows can vary the current file I am looking at has some tabs with as few as 17 rows and as high as 6181. Across all tabs if you were to combine the headers and remove duplicates there are 189 different possible options. The format of the file is the same each week I get the file and the desire output is the same so I figured a macro would help a ton here. I have spent the last several hours working with Chat-GPT in an attempt to make this work with no success. What I want to do is make a new tab called CombinedData that has all 189 different possible headers and then move every row of data from all the tabs into this one with their values going into the proper columns based on header names. Below is the code that Chat GPT got me before I gave up.

```
    Sub CombineTabs()
    Dim combinedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim originalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim header As Range
    Dim targetCol As Long

    ' Create a new sheet for the combined data
    Set combinedSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    combinedSheet.Name = "CombinedData"

    ' Loop through all sheets in the original workbook
    For Each originalSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ' Loop through each header in the Summary sheet
            For Each header In originalSheet.Range("A1:BI1")
                ' Get the target column in the Combined sheet
                targetCol = targetCol + 1

                ' Copy the header to the Combined sheet
                combinedSheet.Cells(1, targetCol).Value = header.Value

                ' Copy the values from the original sheet to the Combined sheet
                Dim lastRowCombined As Long
                lastRowCombined = combinedSheet.Cells(combinedSheet.Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).Row

                combinedSheet.Cells(2, targetCol).Resize(originalSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = originalSheet.Columns(header.Column).Value

                ' Remove duplicates in the Combined sheet
                lastRowCombined = combinedSheet.Cells(combinedSheet.Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).Row
                combinedSheet.Range(combinedSheet.Cells(2, targetCol), combinedSheet.Cells(lastRowCombined, targetCol)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, header:=xlNo
            Next header
    Next originalSheet
End Sub
```

The code runs without error but it just tries to put the tabs next to each other on the Combined Data tab and not all the data is coming over. So I gave up on AI help and turned to the combined wisdom of the minds of stack overflow.

The true end game of this project is that once in a single tab we will upload the data into a SQL database each week so that we can query the data and add it to reports/dashboards

Edit1: To answer some questions there are duplicate header names on any one sheet but there are duplicates when looking at different sheets.

Comment: "if you were to combine the headers and remove duplicates" - can a header be duplicated on the same worksheet, or all all headers unique on a given worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams each worksheet has unique headers. the duplicates only arise when combining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Assuming there are no duplicate header names on each sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vKey, oDic, arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, iC As Long, iRes As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, cbSht As Worksheet
    Const CB_SHT = "CombinedData"
    Const MAX_COL = 60 ' modify as needed
    ' Create CombinedData sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cbSht = Sheets(CB_SHT)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cbSht Is Nothing Then
        Set cbSht = Sheets.Add
        cbSht.Name = CB_SHT
    Else
        cbSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    iR = 2
    ' loop through worksheet
    For Each oSht In Worksheets
        If oSht.Name <> CB_SHT Then
            LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 1 Then
                LastCol = oSht.Cells(1, oSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1", oSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                arrData = rngData.Value ' load data into an array
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    If Not oDic.exists(arrData(1, j)) Then
                        oDic(arrData(1, j)) = oDic.Count + 1
                    End If
                Next
                ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) - 1, 1 To oDic.Count)
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    iC = oDic(arrData(1, j))
                    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
                        arrRes(i - 1, iC) = arrData(i, j)
                    Next
                Next
                ' Write ouput to CombinedData sheet
                cbSht.Cells(iR, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRes), oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
                iR = iR + UBound(arrRes)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Populate headers
    ReDim arrRes(0, 1 To oDic.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each vKey In oDic.Keys
        i = i + 1
        arrRes(0, i) = vKey
    Next
    cbSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, oDic.Count).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to work and it is blazing fast. I still need to data validate but it looks perfect. Once again humans beat AI.

Comment: Also i have a lot of googling to do in order to even begin to understand what you did here. Thank you so much.

Comment: AI is not proficient in coding at the moment, but it can assist you in understanding the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Taller beat me to it but posting anyway...

```vb
Sub CombineTabs()
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rngData As Range
    Dim header As Range, dict As Object, hdr As String, rwPaste As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'for tracking unique headers
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case-insensitive

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Create a new sheet for the combined data
    Set wsAll = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count))
    wsAll.Name = "CombinedData"
    rwPaste = 2 'start pasting here

    ' Loop through all sheets in the original workbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsAll.Name Then
            lastRow = LastOccupiedRow(ws)
            lastCol = LastOccupiedColumn(ws)
            If lastRow > 1 Then  'any data to copy?
                Set rngData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)) 'all data
                For Each header In rngData.rows(1).Cells 'loop over header row
                    hdr = header.Value
                    If Not dict.Exists(hdr) Then              'new header?
                        dict.Add hdr, dict.count + 1          'add to dictionary
                        wsAll.Cells(1, dict(hdr)).Value = hdr 'add header to summary sheet
                    End If
                    'copy data below header over to summary sheet
                    header.Offset(1).Resize(rngData.rows.count - 1).Copy _
                                           wsAll.Cells(rwPaste, dict(hdr))
                Next header
                rwPaste = rwPaste + lastRow - 1 'increment destination row for next worksheet
            End If 'any data to copy
        End If     'not wsAll
    Next ws
End Sub

Function LastOccupiedColumn(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedColumn = f.Column
End Function
Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.row
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Combine Worksheets With Different Headers

**Class Module `cWorksheetProperties`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Public DataRange As Range
Public Headers As Variant
Public RowsCount As Long
Public ColumnsCount As Long
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CombineWorksheets()

    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1" ' fixed (due to 'CurrentRegion')
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "CombinedData"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dsh As Object:
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
   
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Dim swsp As cWorksheetProperties, sws As Worksheet
    Dim Headers() As Variant, Header As Variant
    Dim sc As Long, dc As Long

    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        Set swsp = New cWorksheetProperties
        With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
            Headers = .Rows(1).Value
            swsp.RowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
            swsp.ColumnsCount = .Columns.Count
            Set swsp.DataRange = .Resize(swsp.RowsCount).Offset(1)
        End With
        For sc = 1 To swsp.ColumnsCount
            Header = Headers(1, sc)
            If Not dict.Exists(Header) Then
                dc = dc + 1
                dict(Header) = dc
                Headers(1, sc) = dc
            Else
                Headers(1, sc) = dict(Header)
            End If
        Next sc
        swsp.Headers = Headers
        coll.Add swsp
    Next sws
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add
    dws.Name = DST_SHEET_NAME
    
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(, dict.Count)
    drrg.Value = dict.Keys
    Set dict = Nothing
    Set drrg = drrg.Offset(1)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    For Each swsp In coll
        With swsp
            Set drg = drrg.Resize(.RowsCount)
            For sc = 1 To .ColumnsCount
                drg.Columns(.Headers(1, sc)).Value _
                    = .DataRange.Columns(sc).Value
            Next sc
            Set drrg = drrg.Offset(.RowsCount)
        End With
    Next swsp
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Worksheets combined.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```